# Cloudera Hue alternative for Hortonworks

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, oozie, hue, ambari

Like hue is used to deploy oozie jobs using oozie editor, what alternative do we have, when using hortonworks ambari? I want to deploy oozie jobs but also want to avoid oozie cli client.

Answer (score 0):

Latest versions of Ambari support the Oozie Workflow Manager.

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.7.1.0/bk_workflow-management/content/ch_wfm_basics.html

Or, you could download and install/configure Hue on your cluster; Ambari doesn't need to be the central configuration component of the cluster